# Linux print server in a web interface

Tags: linux, print-server

I would want a Linux print server in the form of a web interface, where you upload a PDF, doc, JPG, PNG, PPT, TXT, HTM etc file in a file upload box, and then that file is printed to a USB connected Samsung CLX-3185 printer.

Which linux distribution and software should I use then? I would want it to support so many file formats its possible.

Comment: you specifically *don't* want the user to add a network printer (through cups)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cups is the default print server on most Linux distributions. You should use any of the major distributions that you are comfortable with.

Cups supports Postscript, PDF, txt, jpg, and png without any conversion. The other formats should be printed to a file as PDF.

You will need a web app to send the jobs to cups. I couldn't find one, but you could easily write one in your favorite language that does the following:

1. Allow a user to upload a file to the server.
2. Run the following command:

   lpr -P<print queue> <uploaded file>

Comment: Thank you. Great idea. What I intend to do, is a "driverless printing" feature, like those provided to wifi customers at schools and such. Then I can print from my Sony Ericsson Xperia X1 and other things that does not support printing at all... Should look into this, I mark your solution as a answer...

Comment: I just found http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/batch-command-line-file-conversion-with.html to help you convert other file types to pdf.